# Who is one who participates in skulduggery?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

Is there an English word for one who participates in skulduggery? The form I'm looking for is something like 'skuldugger', but I wasn't able to find that word anywhere in the OED. There are probably other options that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Swindler or con-artist.

Comment: @ermanen: Given we're supposed to be [linguists, etymologists, and {serious} English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), we should all either know the word already, or be able to easily look it up. And given there are apparently no words etymologically related to ***skulduggery***, I can't see what good it would do for OP to offer any such links as evidence of "prior research".

Comment: @ermanen: oic. I'll leave it for a bit, otherwise what we're saying *now* might look even more odd. I don't yet have an opinion regarding whether/why it might be OT, so I guess I'm open to persuasion either way. Might it be relevant that I get the impression from OED that it's a variant of an earlier "nonce word" ***sculduddery**?*

Comment: If you mean 'what is the agent noun corresponding to skulduggery', I'd say that the fact that the OED (if you really mean the OED and not one of its smaller relatives) doesn't give one is a strong argument that there isn't such a word. There are plenty of synonyms for _shyster_ with a wide variety of connotations to choose from.

Comment: The usual construction when making such a word would be "skulduggerer".  Just as someone who commits adultery is an adulterer.

Comment: @Oldcat: and somebody who commits *trickery* is a *trickerer*, while somebody who commits *forgery* is an *forgerer*? I thought the words were *trickster* and *forger*.

Comment: +1, @PeterShor. Let's not forget the word for somebody who commits buggery, while we're at it.  So to speak.

Comment: Interesting side-bar:
Skulduggery seems to have Germanic sources.
The Lord's Prayer in German and Swedish (or Norwegian) appears to say: Forgive us our skulduggery (skuldiggern) as we forgive those who skuldig (or some similar word) against us.
So, originally it meant to sin or to trespass. Not necessarily any trickery or Nixonian plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider  *skulduggerist*. Although not a  “dictionary word”, it has appeared with appropriate sense in a number of web pages, eg:

> • Prizefighter. Whiskey drinker. Habitual **skulduggerist**. International vagabond. – from Brett Koshkin's self-description at [mixcloud](http://www.mixcloud.com/brett-koshkin/)
>   • ...the lovely little matilda,her crooky parents,the dumb or even crooky brother,the gusty and adventrous dainty friends ,the perfect **skulduggerist**, and the tyrannical bellowing miss trunchbull... – from a review of Roald Dahl's *Matilda* at [goodreads.com](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/805984712)
>    • Stupid science has put an end to those glorious days when **skulduggerist** scholars would forge entire museum wings worth of false antiquities to advance their careers or sell on the black market. – from a [Cancer horoscope](http://www.thelmagazine.com/Horoscope/archives/2008/09/17/horoscope) at thelmagazine.com

Comment: @ermanen: I dunno. OED does actually list the *verb* form ***to skuldug*** (defined as *to extract by trickery*), and that has what looks like maybe [a couple of hundred relevant written instances in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22skuldugger%22+-%22Stanley+Skuldugger%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). And such "regular derivations" is sufficiently common in English that it doesn't require evidence supporting the *principle* itself. Perhaps the *real* question is *"Which (and why) would native speakers prefer: **skuldugger, skulduggerer** or **skulduggerist**"?*

Comment: @ermanen: In this case, the numbers aren't important. I assume to a first approximation we all agree dictionaries in general don't list any word for OP's context which is etymologically related to his "original". And in any case I believe it's valid to post an answer to a swr question saying *"There is no such word"*. I like that jwpat starts by saying ***consider*** "skulduggerist", and acknowledging that it doesn't appear in dictionaries...

Comment: ...I assume the current "Unclear" closevote is yours. If the OP simply wants *any* word that could reasonably be used to designate a person who habitually engages in skulduggery, then I will consider it "Too Broad" or "POB". But as a general principle I'm not keen on casting an "Unclear" CV unless there's a comment pinpointing the nature of the vagueness, and/or sufficient time has passed to been allow the OP to improve things. I'm really trying not to be awkward here, please accept my apologies if it seems that I am.